# How to use an arraylist from another class?

Tags: java, bluej

This is the class where I made my arraylist in and I am trying to use this arraylist over in another class but it keeps on giving me the error of not finding the metho

```
public HumanResource(String fileName)
{
   file = new FileReader(fileName);
   ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
   
   
   for (int k = 0; k < file.getLines().size(); k++)
   {
       employeeList.add(new Employee (file.getLines().get(k)));
   
    }
   
   
}
public ArrayList<Employee> GetemployeeList()
{
    return employeeList;
}
```

This is the class that I am trying to use the arraylist in but to no avail.

```
private String employee;
private int employeeRank;
private int employeeID;
private int employeeExperience;
private int employeeAge;
private String employeeName;



public Employee(String employee)
{  
    employee = new String();
    ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = employee.GetemployeeList();
```

Comment: That code won't compile.  Is 'HumanResource' (don't you mean 'Person'?) supposed to be a class or a method?  What you have written is neither.  The same goes for 'Employee'.  And assigning a new String to an otherwise-ignore parameter 'employee' suggests you lack knowledge of basic semantics. I'd suggest reading some Java tutorials before jumping in to code.

Comment: Not as written it isn't. `public HumanResource(String fileName)`.  It lacks a return type.  And more to the point, if it's supposed to be a method, then `employeeList` **does not exist** outside the method - it is declared inside the method.  You cannot reference it because there's nothing to reference.  I imagine that what you want is for `HumanResource` ro return the employee list, and then you can call `HumanResource` from 'Employee`.

Comment: Btw, you probably should stick to the convention that class names start with a capital letter, and methods and variables do not.  That makes it easier for other Java programmers to read.

Comment: Just pass the reference to the other method

Comment: One more issue that should be noted is that in your Employee constructor you call `employee.GetemployeeList()`, but `employee` is a string.  Java strings don't come with a built-in method named "GetemployeeList()".  Your GetemployeeList() method is in whatever class your first code snippet is in, not the String class.